# PHPUnit & ZF2: Error "no names found, cannot describe anything"

Tags: unix, phpunit, zend-framework2

Can anyone explain what this error might means?

I am trying to set up a phpunit test using ZF2, but everytime I try to run the phpunit command, I get this error.

Answer (score 0):

If you install PHPUnit via Composer you can receive this error message.
Do not have anything related to ZF2.

In [this commit](https://github.com/sebastianbergmann/phpunit/commit/43433ef6101fe17c037d03dd12921ab94a666ae1) Sebastian fix this issue.

You only need to update to "3.7.x-dev" instead of ">=3.7.1" or something similar